# Discrepancy with R regular expression match

Tags: r, regex

I can't figure out why this R regular expression doesn't match **both** of these two strings.  As I understand it, this expression should match any string with the same lower-case letter appearing twice within the string.  It matches one of the strings ("Moro"), but not the second ("moro"), even though both strings contain a repeated lower-case "o".  What's going on here?

Executed in R (3.4.3):

`grep("([a-z]).*\\1", c("Moro", "moro"), value=TRUE)`

`[1] "Moro"`

The same thing occurs with this regex, which I believe is identical to the one above:

`grep("([[:lower:]]).*\\1", c("Moro", "moro"), value=TRUE)`

`[1] "Moro"`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a regex flavor issue. If you set `perl = T`, it works:

```
grep("([a-z]).*\\1", c("Moro", "moro", "mora"), value=TRUE, perl = T)
# [1] "Moro" "moro"
```

Worth noting that `stringr` and `stringi` work out-of-the-box:

```
stringr::str_detect(c("Moro", "moro", "mora"), "([a-z]).*\\1")
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

stringi::stri_detect(c("Moro", "moro", "mora"), regex = "([a-z]).*\\1")
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but my guess is because it tries to match *any* character. If you use simple `[o]` it will work:

```
grep("([a-z]).*\\1", c("Moro", "moro"), value=TRUE)
# [1] "Moro"
grep("([o]).*\\1", c("Moro", "moro"), value=TRUE)
# [1] "Moro" "moro"
```

Comment: Doesn't really explain the difference of why Moro works by moro doesn't in OP's code...

Comment: The `\\1` relates to the found value - not to the related part of the regular expression; so for `Moro` the `\\1` is `o` and for `moro` it is `m`. In `moro` is no sequence `m.*m`